# c++: Parsing and File i/o

Tags: c++, file, parsing, io

I'm trying to write a code that pulls from a txt file (input.txt) that looks like this:

```
1,2,3
Hello
2,3,4
Music
1,3,4
Dodie
3,0,1
Kitty
5,1,0
Cheese
```

And prints out the word as many times as the numbers above it added up. So the first one would be 1+2+3=6, so it would print: Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello,Hello

Currently it is only printing out the first sum, then stopping. (currently printing the sum just for clarification). I feel like I need another loop but I'm not sure.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>


int main() {
    std::ifstream inFile ("input.txt");
    if (inFile.is_open()) {
        std::string str;
        int sum = 2;
        int a, b, c;
        char z;
        while (inFile >> a >> z >> b >> z >> c && z == ',') {
            sum = a + b + c;
            std::cout << sum;
        }

        while (inFile >> str) {
            for (int i=0; i<sum; i++) {
                std::cout << str << ",";
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use your debugger to run your program one line at a time and see what it does, and why. This is what a debugger is for. Also, remember The Golden Rule Of Computer Programming: a computer will always do exactly what you tell to do, and not what you want it to do. Unless you tell your computer to read the line with the numbers, then read the line with the text, and when done repeat the whole thing, the computer won't do that. What did you tell your computer to do, above? Read lines with the numbers, first. Then read the lines with the text. That's it. Is that what you want your computer to do?

Comment: Excellent improvement over previous question, Lauren.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (inFile >> a >> z >> b >> z >> c && z == ','){
                    sum = a + b + c;
                    std::cout << sum;}
```

This part of the code is designed to read lines with the structure you made it to read, num,num,num. So when it reads the first line it goes on to the next line and can't find a number and terminates. You should add the logic to read the next line as here as well and combine the numbers and the word together into one read such as

```
std:string ex=""   
while (inFile >> a >> z >> b >> z >> c >> ex && z == ','){
                    sum = a + b + c;
                    // add the logic for printing here
                    std::cout << sum;}
```

And get rid of the second while loop that comes afterwards. I suggest you look up a bit about these file operations a bit because your error here seems to be caused by your lack of knowledge of them. Hope this helps!

Comment: True, my bad will edit.